# Logon Windows XP with smartcard

Tags: windows-xp, smartcard, authentication

Suppose that I had an SDK to develop an application on smartcard to store my password and acts as an Authentication server toward Windows XP. That is, when an user wants to log on Windows XP with a certain username and password, Windows XP will send this account's information to smartcard and wait for a response. If smartcard says YES, user will be granted to log in.

This is my idea but I don't know how to implement it with Windows XP. I have designed an interface between smartcard and Windows XP but I don't know where to begin? I must write my logon application (prefered in C#.NET) to replace the actual standard logon process of Windows XP? How can I intervene in the Windows XP process?

I highly appreciate your helps

Best regards,
Hai-Binh LE

Answer (score 1):

[Smart Card Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

Write custom GINA:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_identification_and_authentication

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163786.aspx

But it is not trivial task.